# Validate several validation groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have 2 validation groups, VG1 and VG2.  I have a button `BtnInsert` that saves data into `Datasource`. Its Validation Group is VG2. Now, I want to validate both VG1 and VG2 when a user clicks the `BtnInsert`.

```
protected void BtnInsert_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    // validate VG1
    Page.Validate("VG1");
    // Page.Validate("VG2") is not required as BtnInsert is of that group
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
       // call insert function
    } 
}
```

Is this code right, and by clicking `BtnInsert`, both groups are validated?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you won't get client-side validation of VG2, but otherwise I can't see that it shouldn't work. (There is probably a client-side event and a method you could call to duplicate the behavior for the client)